# XSD restrictions are not working at all on jboss eap 6.1

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl, soapui

Here is my XSD

```
<element name="FirstName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" >
<simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
<length value="5"></length>         
</restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
```

when post a request through SOAP UI, not validating that restriction at all. I am not sure what's wrong in my code

Comment: Can you show the invalid request which you think soapui did not validate them? Then why the question states `not working at all on jboss` and not tagged to jboss as well?

Comment: this is what I was sending as a request <FirstName>KEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</FirstName> One thing I want to add is I am using Apache CXF framework with Spring.

Comment: Have you tried validating request from soapui by using `Alt+v`?